# Code slower despite what gprof says

Tags: c++, gprof

I've been given a c++ code to optimize, and the first step is to introduce parallelism with OpenMP. I was able to identify several functions that badly needed optimization, so I focused on them.

The problem is that the execution time has been multiplied by about 2, when the profiling files seems to tell me that it should be much faster ..

Here are the gprof profile I get without using OpenMP :

```
38.07      5.55     5.55                             __tcf_0
 20.99      8.61     3.06 86196302     0.04     0.04  is_neighbor(int, int, int, int, double)
 13.24     10.54     1.93   425940     4.53     4.53  Ellips::data_fiting(double*, int, int, double) const
  9.05     11.86     1.32                             _fu51___ZSt4cout
  5.90     12.72     0.86  5645243     0.15     0.15  Ellips::Ellips()
  3.70     13.26     0.54  4013067     0.13     0.13  intersect(Ellips&, Ellips&)
  2.40     13.61     0.35                             dgemv_
  1.44     13.82     0.21                             ddot_
  1.23     14.00     0.18 141257881     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_position(int)
  1.03     14.15     0.15                             __tcf_0
  0.82     14.27     0.12   594893     0.20     0.20  Ellips::Ellips(double, double, int, int)
  0.41     14.33     0.06     7099     8.45   400.75  Configuration::Configuration(double, double, int, int, int, int, double*, double)
  0.34     14.38     0.05  3203279     0.02     0.02  Ellips::operator=(Ellips const&)
  0.34     14.43     0.05                             ceil
  0.21     14.46     0.03                             dnrm2_
  0.14     14.48     0.02                             _fu32___ZSt4cout
  0.14     14.50     0.02                             dcopy_
  0.14     14.52     0.02                             dscal_
  0.07     14.53     0.01  7775127     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_Ellips(int)
  0.07     14.54     0.01  6239588     0.00     0.00  Ellips::~Ellips()
  0.07     14.55     0.01  4349523     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_data_fit(int)
  0.07     14.56     0.01     7097     1.41     1.41  Graph<float, float, float>::maxflow(bool, Block<int>*)
  0.07     14.57     0.01                             _fu53___ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
  0.07     14.58     0.01                             floor
  0.00     14.58     0.00 432232036     0.00     0.00  Configuration::save_config(std::string)
  0.00     14.58     0.00  1180034     0.00     0.00  Ellips::data_fiting(double, double*, double*, double, int, int, double) const
  0.00     14.58     0.00  1173980     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_cx() const
  0.00     14.58     0.00  1164513     0.00     0.02  Configuration::add_Ellips(Ellips const&, int, double)
  0.00     14.58     0.00  1157360     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_cy() const
  0.00     14.58     0.00   425940     0.00     0.00  shift_cost_exp1(double, double)
  0.00     14.58     0.00    23625     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::augment(Graph<float, float, float>::arc*)
  0.00     14.58     0.00    22504     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::process_sink_orphan(Graph<float, float, float>::node*)
  0.00     14.58     0.00    21293     0.00    27.35  Configuration::operator=(Configuration const&)
  0.00     14.58     0.00    14203     0.00     0.23  Configuration::~Configuration()
  0.00     14.58     0.00    14196     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_nb_Ellipses()
  0.00     14.58     0.00     7097     0.00    34.30  Configuration::Configuration(Ellips const&, int, double, int)
  0.00     14.58     0.00     7097     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::maxflow_init()
  0.00     14.58     0.00     7097     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::reset()
  0.00     14.58     0.00     2406     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_a() const
  0.00     14.58     0.00     2406     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_b() const
  0.00     14.58     0.00     2406     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_theta() const
  0.00     14.58     0.00     1137     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::process_source_orphan(Graph<float, float, float>::node*)
  0.00     14.58     0.00        7     0.00    38.00  Configuration::Configuration(Configuration const&)
  0.00     14.58     0.00        3     0.00     0.32  Configuration::Configuration()
  0.00     14.58     0.00        2     0.00     0.00  min_max_val(_IplImage*, double&, double&)
  0.00     14.58     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  convert_char_to_double(_IplImage*, double*)
  0.00     14.58     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::reallocate_nodes(int)
  0.00     14.58     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::Graph(int, int, void (*)(char*))
```

And here is the one I get with OpenMP (The code is a recursive algorithm with no real "ending", the two profiles have been obtained after about 7000 iterations of the main loop).

```
36.57      4.45     4.45                             __tcf_0
 25.72      7.58     3.13 86434458     0.04     0.04  is_neighbor(int, int, int, int, double)
 12.41      9.09     1.51                             _fu51___ZSt4cout
  7.97     10.06     0.97  5646276     0.17     0.17  Ellips::Ellips()
  4.35     10.59     0.53  4020048     0.13     0.13  intersect(Ellips&, Ellips&)
  2.47     10.89     0.30                             dgemv_
  1.73     11.10     0.21                             ddot_
  1.64     11.30     0.20 141852099     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_position(int)
  1.15     11.44     0.14     7038    19.89   164.95  Configuration::Configuration(double, double, int, int, int, int, double*, double)
  1.07     11.57     0.13   589659     0.22     0.22  Ellips::Ellips(double, double, int, int)
  0.99     11.69     0.12                             __tcf_0
  0.90     11.80     0.11   422280     0.26     0.33  Ellips::data_fiting(double*, int, int, double) const
  0.74     11.89     0.09  3208793     0.03     0.03  Ellips::operator=(Ellips const&)
  0.41     11.94     0.05                             ceil
  0.25     11.97     0.03   422280     0.07     0.07  shift_cost_exp1(double, double)
  0.25     12.00     0.03                             GOMP_parallel_end
  0.25     12.03     0.03                             _fu53___ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE
  0.16     12.05     0.02    21110     0.95    32.56  Configuration::operator=(Configuration const&)
  0.16     12.07     0.02     7036     2.84     2.84  Graph<float, float, float>::maxflow(bool, Block<int>*)
  0.16     12.09     0.02                             _fu32___ZSt4cout
  0.16     12.11     0.02                             daxpy_
  0.16     12.13     0.02                             dnrm2_
  0.08     12.14     0.01  1171018     0.01     0.04  Configuration::add_Ellips(Ellips const&, int, double)
  0.08     12.15     0.01                             GOMP_parallel_start
  0.08     12.16     0.01                             dcopy_
  0.08     12.17     0.01                             dgemm_
  0.00     12.17     0.00 432088679     0.00     0.00  Configuration::save_config(std::string)
  0.00     12.17     0.00  7813683     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_Ellips(int)
  0.00     12.17     0.00  6235383     0.00     0.00  Ellips::~Ellips()
  0.00     12.17     0.00  4360587     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_data_fit(int)
  0.00     12.17     0.00  1187310     0.00     0.00  Ellips::data_fiting(double, double*, double*, double, int, int, double) const
  0.00     12.17     0.00  1163572     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_cx() const
  0.00     12.17     0.00  1147536     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_cy() const
  0.00     12.17     0.00    35748     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::augment(Graph<float, float, float>::arc*)
  0.00     12.17     0.00    33436     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::process_sink_orphan(Graph<float, float, float>::node*)
  0.00     12.17     0.00    14081     0.00     0.00  Configuration::~Configuration()
  0.00     12.17     0.00    14074     0.00     0.00  Configuration::get_nb_Ellipses()
  0.00     12.17     0.00     7036     0.00    39.10  Configuration::Configuration(Ellips const&, int, double, int)
  0.00     12.17     0.00     7036     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::maxflow_init()
  0.00     12.17     0.00     7036     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::reset()
  0.00     12.17     0.00     2424     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_a() const
  0.00     12.17     0.00     2424     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_b() const
  0.00     12.17     0.00     2424     0.00     0.00  Ellips::get_theta() const
  0.00     12.17     0.00     2355     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::process_source_orphan(Graph<float, float, float>::node*)
  0.00     12.17     0.00        7     0.00    44.91  Configuration::Configuration(Configuration const&)
  0.00     12.17     0.00        3     0.00     0.37  Configuration::Configuration()
  0.00     12.17     0.00        2     0.00     0.00  min_max_val(_IplImage*, double&, double&)
  0.00     12.17     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  convert_char_to_double(_IplImage*, double*)
  0.00     12.17     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::reallocate_nodes(int)
  0.00     12.17     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Graph<float, float, float>::Graph(int, int, void (*)(char*))
```

Is there a problem with how I'm using the profiler ? Or does this come from the code itself ? It takes about 12 seconds to complete 1000 iterations with OpenMP, whereas it takes about 31 seconds with OpenMP (using omp_get_wtime() and not clock())

Comment: If you're using `clock` for the non-OpenMP version, you're comparing apples to oranges; `clock` measures CPU time, `omp_get_wtime` measures "wall clock" time.

Comment: I'm using omp_get_wtime in both examples, I just commented out the pragmas used to optimize Ellips::data_fitting() for the one without OpenMP